# CSS or JavaScript text transitions for a JavaScript clock

Tags: javascript, css

I've made a clock with Javascript. It's quite simple.

```js
var today = new Date();
var h;
if (today.getHours() == 0) h = '12';
else if (today.getHours() < 12) h = today.getHours;
else if (today.getHours() == 12) h = '12';
else h = today.getHours() - 12;
    var m;
if (today.getMinutes() < 10) m = '0' + today.getMinutes();
else m = today.getMinutes();
    var s;
if (today.getSeconds() < 10) s = today.getSeconds();
else s = today.getSeconds();

document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
```

```css
#time {

 top: 20px;
 left: 7px;
 width: 320px;
 font-size: 40px;
 text-align: left;
 font-family: 'Segoe UI Light';

}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">
    <div id="main-wrapper"> 
        <div id="center">
            <div id="time"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Now, all I want to do is to add a simple transition to it so that the numbers fade when they change. However, I haven't been able to find a good way to do so, either with CSS or JavaScript.

This is probably a simple question but googling for a solution (and searching here on Stack Exchange) just made me more confused.

Comment: as there is no html in your question, there's no amount of CSS or javascript that will produce any transitions

Comment: You didn't show the part of the code that displays the time. Neither the one that changes the time. Short: the code you show is not related to the question.

Comment: @JaromandaX: sorry about that. I've edited the relevant HTML and CSS bits into my question.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work?

Comment: @DanielCheung I have no idea how to use this website, sorry. It's just been really confusing for me.

Comment: I fixed it, but you are missing the `startTime()` function and your declaration of `m` seems to be missing something.

Comment: @DanielCheung woo, I fixed it! Thanks so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this? Your original code doesn't work for the extra zero. That means this code is made from scratch

The clock uses JS + CSS

### JS

```
var c = document.getElementById("clock");
Date.prototype.hhmmss = function() {
    var hh = this.getHours().toString();
    var mm = this.getMinutes().toString();
    var ss  = this.getSeconds().toString();
    return (hh[1]?hh:"0"+hh[0]) + ":" + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + ":" + (ss[1]?ss:"0"+ss[0]);
};
function clock(){
    c.innerHTML += ("<span class='tick'>"+ new Date().hhmmss()+"</span>");
    setTimeout(function(){     
        var old = c.getElementsByClassName("tick")[0];
        old.className += " remove";
        setTimeout(function(){
            var old = c.getElementsByClassName("tick")[0];
            old.parentNode.removeChild(old);
        },250);
    }, 750);
}
var x = setInterval(function(){clock()}, 1000);
```

### CSS

```
.tick {
    animation: appear 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.tick.remove {
    opacity:0
}

@keyframes appear {
    0% {
        opacity:0; 
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pduyqr9v/3/

Comment: Wow, did you seriously write all that for me? For a post that got downvoted three times? I am honestly amazed at your effort. Thank you *so* much. There is a *ton* that I can learn from this code. It's amazing. I don't know how to thank you enough. Unfortunately I only have a measly upvote, which doesn't even show because I don't have enough reputation :/

Comment: @JonesBill You,re welcome. I believe everybody has a start in their life, they all need help at that point. This platform should not be one of a small community, but also help those who don't know :)